# How to squash merge using git2go?

Tags: git, go

I'd like to perform "git merge --squash" with git2go, such that I get one commit for the merge. That commit message could be all of the other commit messages listed together, but it would only be one commit.

So far, I'm thinking I could rebase the branch to itself, squashing commits, and then merge? Or I could try to do the merge, then try to do a soft git reset, then make a new commit with all the new changes - In this case I'd lose all of the commit messages though. Or I could just give up and use the command line via golang.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it were me, I would use `merge_trees` instead of `merge`.  This will give you the resultant merge tree, just like a normal merge.  I would then commit it with the appropriate parents.  (Sorry, I don't have any example code, I'm not a gopher.)

Comment: @EdwardThomson, can you elaborate on the difference? The documentation is just the autogenerated stuff, there's no examples or explanations, I just have to infer meaning from variable names :(

Comment: `merge` will set up a merge in the working directory, including setting up a file called `MERGE_HEAD` that shows the parents of the merge.  It's the equivalent of `git merge --no-commit`.  When you do a commit, it will read that information and create a proper merge commit.  `merge_trees` does not touch the working directory at all.  It just gives you an `index` that represents the merge result.  You can then write that tree (`git_index_write_tree`) and create a commit that points to that tree.

Comment: @EdwardThomson So is that similar to doing git merge feature, then git reset master, then git add --all and git commit? It would grab all of the files changed but not all of the commits essentially. How can we preserve commit messages though?